# How to include a moment in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, momentjs

I have a blog that I am creating and I've just set up AJAX to perform the create comment and edit comment functions. However, when the comment is displayed, I use moment to show when it was posted. However, I'm not sure how to reference this in the JQuery code. Here's my Ajax code when updating the original HTML. Here's my standard code to display a comment:

```
<!--================== COMMENTS DISPLAY SECTION    ====================================================================-->
<div id="comments">
    <% blog.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
    <div>
        <div class="jumbotron comment">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img class="comment-ico" src = "<%=comment.author.image%>">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h4><%=comment.author.username%></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 date">
                     <%= moment(comment.created).fromNow()%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="comment-container"><p><%=comment.text%></p></div>
```

And here's the ajax:

```
// update comment
$('#comments').on('submit', '#edit-comment-form', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
// get info from form
var formData = $(this).serialize();
var formAction = $(this).attr('action');
var $originalItem = $(this).parent('.comment-container');
$.ajax({
    url: formAction,
    data: formData,
    type: 'PUT',
    originalItem: $originalItem,
    success: function(data) {
        var blog_id = location.pathname.replace("/blogs/", "");
        this.originalItem.html(
            `
    <div class="jumbotron comment">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <img class="comment-ico" src = "${data.author.image}">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                <h4>${data.author.username}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div><p>${data.text}</p></div>

  <form id="edit-comment-form" action="/blogs/${blog_id}/comments/  ${data._id}" method="POST" id="newComment">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4"  name="comment   [text]">${data.text}</textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 choice">
                <a class="edit">Edit</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <form id="delete-form" action="/blogs/${blog_id}/comments/${data._id}?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                    <input type="submit" class="button-delete" value="Delete">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <hr class = "style-three">
            `
            );
    }
});
});
```

I need to incorporate this line into the ajax code:

```
<%= moment(comment.created).fromNow()%>
```

But not sure how to replace the ejs etc...

Comment: Personally I'd format this on the server and send back what to display in the UI

Comment: thanks Darren - how exactly though would you do this?